# magento - changing footer - php code

Tags: php, html, css, magento, footer

This newbie is trying to change the footer of a magento store. The template used is ultimo. The footer is build up with 6 footers, and the template creates by itself the classes "grid 12-2". And apparently for the blocks the classes "grid12-2"

The last/6th footer block is disabled and not for showing. The 5 other footer blocks still have the classes "grid 12-2"

I would like to change the 5th footerblock in the class "grid 12-3". How can I do this?

```
<?php if (!empty($b['primary_bottom'])): ?>
    <div class="footer-primary-bottom grid12-12">
        <div class="<?php if(!empty($b['primary'])) echo 'footer-primary-bottom-spacing '; ?>clearer">

            <?php if (!empty($b['primary_bottom']['left'])): ?>
                <div class="item item-left clearer block_footer_primary_bottom_left">
                    <?php echo $b['primary_bottom']['left']; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (!empty($b['primary_bottom']['right'])): ?>
                <div class="item item-right clearer block_footer_primary_bottom_right">
                    <?php echo $b['primary_bottom']['right']; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (!empty($b['primary_bottom']['newsletter'])): ?>
                <div class="item item-right newsletter-wrapper clearer">
                    <?php echo $b['primary_bottom']['newsletter']; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div> 
    </div> <!-- end: footer-primary-bottom -->
```

Comment: Really nobody an idea???

Comment: you need trace the code, what actualy come into that array every time, so you get idea what you need to do further.